# How to make a php echo from a mysql var

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have my var defined in my mysql DDBB as follows:

```
set @myVar = 1;
```

So I want to consult this var from my PHP code this way:

```
$sql="select @myVar";
$link = connectDB();//connects directly to the ddbb and returns connection object.
if(!$result=$link->query($sql)){
   throw new Exception(" Mysql error ".$link->errno);
}
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}
echo ($row['@myVar']);
```

The finally echo should print var value. But nothing is printed. What is wrong with this?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` returns?

Comment: Does it show an undefined error in your logs ?

Comment: Nothing is printed. No error no message... var_dump($row) prints array(1) { ["@cmrNumber"]=> NULL }

Comment: inside your `mysqli_num_rows` check, output something to debug. ie: `echo "We have 1 ";` And just a side note, i hope this is not production code.. :(

Comment: Pls show us the complete code from assigning the mysql user variable a value! It is possible, that the mysql variable does not even exist by the time you try to query its value.

Comment: Pogrindis-> if I make `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)` it prints 1. So It gets into the if sentence.

Comment: If I do the sentence `select @myVar` into mysql it does return var value.

Comment: Declare `$row = [];` first just before `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
}`. And please, change the `if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1)` to `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)`. Then let's see what gets dumped

Comment: I have this sentence because I want to make sure just one row is returned.

Comment: @talk2toyin these will not help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that apparently your code freshly connects to the mysql database and then tries to retrieve a [mysql user defined variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html). According to the linked documentation:

> User-defined variables are session-specific. A user variable defined
>   by one client cannot be seen or used by other clients. (Exception: A
>   user with access to the Performance Schema user_variables_by_thread
>   table can see all user variables for all sessions.) All variables for
>   a given client session are automatically freed when that client exits.

So, any variable defined in another session (database connection) is simply not available to your code. If you need to pass data between database calls, then either persists those in a mysql table, or retrieve the values when they are assigned a value from your php code and preserve the values there.

Comment: I want to use this var as a permanent on the code. So I wanted to save it on the DDBB so it would be accessible, and could be changed for all users. So the correct way to do this should be create a table and save var value on table row?

Comment: Yep, that's one way. The advantage of this is that all users can easily change the variable. If it is a general constant that rarely needs to be changed, then you can save it in a separate php file that you can include in the other php files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demonstration of the problem you're having

```
chris@dev:~$ mysql -e 'set @x=2; select @x'
+------+
| @x   |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
chris@dev:~$ mysql -e 'select @x'
+------+
| @x   |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
```

The variable goes out of scope when a new connection is made.

Comment: So vars defined are session vars. No permanent ones... ok thank you very much for your help!